# Flexbox doesn't work on mobile browsers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

This property `flex-flow` and this one `display:flex;` doesn't work in Safari, mobile Opera, etc. I'm trying to find a problem for about a week and still got nothing.
My code looks this way:

```css
.contentleft,
.contentright {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background: red;
}
.contentcenter {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
}
.contentleft,
.contentright,
.contentcenter {
  display: inline-block;
}
.right,
.left {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 640px) {
  .content {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
    -moz-flex-flow: column;
    -ms-flex-flow: column;
    flex-flow: column;
  }
  .contentright {
    -webkit-order: 2;
    -moz-order: 2;
    -ms-order: 2;
    order: 2;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    /* OLD: Safari,  iOS, Android browser, older WebKit browsers.  */
    display: -moz-flex;
    /* OLD: Firefox (buggy) */
    display: -ms-flex;
    /* MID: IE 10 */
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    -moz-flex-flow: row;
    -ms-flex-flow: row;
    flex-flow: row;
  }
  .contentleft {
    -webkit-order: 3;
    -moz-order: 3;
    -ms-order: 3;
    order: 3;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    /* OLD: Safari,  iOS, Android browser, older WebKit browsers.  */
    display: -moz-flex;
    /* OLD: Firefox (buggy) */
    display: -ms-flex;
    /* MID: IE 10 */
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row;
    -moz-flex-flow: row;
    -ms-flex-flow: row;
    flex-flow: row;
  }
  .contentcenter {
    -webkit-order: 1;
    -moz-order: 1;
    -ms-order: 1;
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="contentleft">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="contentcenter"></div>
  <div class="contentright">
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Link to [CodePen](http://codepen.io/tony_the_coder/pen/bwVgYm)

Thank you beforehand.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276

Comment: You should really check caniuse.com before posting here.

Comment: thanks for that link, I never knew about it. :(